# How to use post method to update the already stored value

Tags: api, rest, go, post, get

For example,
I use post method to create new record like this

```
ID: "1", Isbn: "438227", Title: "Book One", Author: &Author{Firstname: "John", Lastname: "Doe"}}
```

I need same post method to update the data like this

```
ID: "1", Isbn: "5000656", Title: "Book One new", Author: &Author{Firstname: "Johndoe", Lastname: "D"}}
```

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

// Book struct (Model)
type Book struct {
    ID     string  `json:"id"`
    Isbn   string  `json:"isbn"`
    Title  string  `json:"title"`
    Author *Author `json:"author"`
}

// Author struct
type Author struct {
    Firstname string `json:"firstname"`
    Lastname  string `json:"lastname"`
}

// Init books var as a slice Book struct
var books []Book

// Get all books
func getBooks(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(books)
}

// Get single book
func getBook(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    params := mux.Vars(r) // Gets params
    // Loop through books and find one with the id from the params
    for _, item := range books {
        if item.ID == params["id"] {
            json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(item)
            return
        }
    }
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&Book{})
}

// Add new book
func createBook(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    var book Book
    _ = json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&book)
    book.ID = strconv.Itoa(rand.Intn(100000000)) // Mock ID - not safe
    books = append(books, book)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(book)
}

// Delete book
func deleteBook(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    params := mux.Vars(r)
    for index, item := range books {
        if item.ID == params["id"] {
            books = append(books[:index], books[index+1:]...)
            break
        }
    }
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(books)
}

// Main function
func main() {
    // Init router
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    // Hardcoded data - @todo: add database
    books = append(books, Book{ID: "1", Isbn: "438227", Title: "Book One", Author: &Author{Firstname: "John", Lastname: "Doe"}})
    books = append(books, Book{ID: "2", Isbn: "454555", Title: "Book Two", Author: &Author{Firstname: "Steve", Lastname: "Smith"}})

    // Route handles & endpoints
    r.HandleFunc("/books", getBooks).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/books/{id}", getBook).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/books", createBook).Methods("POST")
    r.HandleFunc("/books/{id}", deleteBook).Methods("DELETE")

    // Start server
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", r))
}
```

How to solve this?

Comment: why you don't you use put method and another function for update?

Comment: Another option could be "REST without PUT". This way, all creations and changes should be modeled as commands, like `{"command":"createBook", ...}` and `{"command":"updateBook", ...}` and the like. https://www.thoughtworks.com/radar/techniques/rest-without-put

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to design this.

A straightforward approach:

1. Add another handler `updateBook` that takes the ID and updated information from POST data
2. Hook `updateBook` up to a POST method on some path, like POST on `/books/{id}`

In your existing code, you have all the examples you need to accomplish these: you already have several paths hooked up, and you have the `createBook` handler which grabs data from a POST's body.

It would be odd if the same POST could either create or update records, but you could do that too, I suppose. E.g.: If your POST data has an ID you can update the existing record; otherwise you create a new one.